# How to create json object with the data stored in variables of different datatypes

Tags: json, python-3.x

How to create a json object/csv using below variables data:

```
out = [['core java'],['angular js']]
skills = 'Java'
```

Can someone please tell me how I can get a json object/csv as shown in expected output?

Expected Output:

```
            Java
0           core java
1           angular js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this example:

```
import json

data = {}
data['dynamic_col_name'] = 'dynamic_upcoming_value'
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: In my example the column name should be the data stored in skills variable. @Adam Strauss

Comment: The values of out and skills are dynamic. I am fetching the data from database and storing it in variables. Depending upon the criteria the value of out and skills will change. @Adam Strauss

Comment: My ask is I have to create a josn object/csv in which key/column name should be the value stored in skills variable and values/row should be the values of key variable.@Adam strauss

Comment: @RajeevSrivastava dear then mention it in your question. Dont worry I am going to update my answer.

Comment: Worked. Thanks @Adam Strauss.

Comment: sure @Adam Strauss

Answer (score 1):

Use [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

With `list`:

```py
import csv

out = [['Java'], ['core java'],['angular js']]

with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(out)
```

With `dict`:

```py
import csv

out = [['core javaaaa'],['angular js']]
skills = ['Java']

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=skills)

    writer.writeheader()
    rows = [{skills[idx]: cell for idx, cell in enumerate(row)} for row in out]
    writer.writerows(rows)
```